# Sound Touch in iPhone

Tags: iphone, pitch, soundtouch

Has someone been able to make [**SoundTouch Audio Processing Library**](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/) work for iPhone?

Simple Xcode Demo would be helpful.

I'd just like to change pitch without tempo change.

Comment: SoundTouch is LGPL licensed. Make sure you understand what this license requires.

Comment: According to the FAQ, it's been done before, and the author doesn't think it should be too difficult. Have you tried? If so, what did you try, and what happened? (You're more likely to get help with specific error messages than with a general question like this.)

Comment: did you find any API for iOS ?

Answer (score 3):

try https://github.com/kstenerud/Aural ;)

Answer (score 0):

...try http://LittleEndian.com/developers, pitch-shifter and other sound effects.